# How do I test with rspec a create action when my model belongs_to another model and uses devise for authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, rspec, devise

In my rails app I use devise for authenticating a user. I need to create rspec tests for a controller Arts which belongs_to User.

My Art model is the following:

```
class Art < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :description, :title, :image
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "620x620>", :thumb => "200x200>" }

  validates :title,       :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
  validates :image,       :presence => true
end
```

In my ArtsController I have the following code:

```
class ArtsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @user = current_user
    @art = @user.arts.create(params[:art])
  end
end
```

I am trying to create a test to check if user is redirected to the *sign in* page when it tries to create an art and it is not logged in. So my test looks like this:

```
describe ArtsController do
  describe "When user is not logged in" do
    it "should be redirected to sign in page if creating new art" do
      post :create
      response.should redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
    end
  end    
end
```

But I get the following error:

```
  1) ArtsController When user is not logged in should be redirected to sign in page if creating new art
     Failure/Error: post :create
     ActionController::RoutingError:
       No route matches {:controller=>"arts", :action=>"create"}
     # ./spec/controllers/arts_controller_spec.rb:11:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My routes.rb is like this:

```
Capuccino::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  match "home" => "users#home", :as => :user_home
  resources :users do
    resources :arts
  end
  match "home/art/:id" => "arts#show", :as => :art
  match "home/arts" => "arts#index", :as => :arts
end
```

How does my rspec test should be to perform this test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have any routes for `arts#create` that will take only the controller and action as parameters.

If you want to use your current nested route, you're gonna have to pass along the `:user_id` parameter in your request:

```
it "should be redirected to sign in page if creating new art" do
  post :create, { :user_id => user_id }
  response.should redirect_to '/users/sign_in'
end
```

But since you're trying to test the use case where you **don't** have a `:user_id`, you need a new non-nested route for that.